# How are power transmission mechanisms suspended?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-transmission

I just saw this diagram and it looks like the bottom shaft and the two gears it goes through would just fall down? and this is a confusion I have in general about power transmission mechanisms. How are the parts of the mechanisms suspended while still allowing them to rotate?

[image]

Comment: Is it from a text book ? If so, it might be a mistake from the part of the illustrator. What are rectangles marked `X` ? They might indicate connection to the main body.

Comment: It might be just a simplified diagram illustrating the interaction of the gears in which the supports for the shafts is  of secondary consideration.

Comment: https://www.cars.com/articles/what-is-a-dual-clutch-transmission-427627/

Comment: For a schematic representation like that the drawer tends to leave out fiddly bits like supports because those distract from the core function the drawing is trying to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is a tad more complicated - toro.com/en/parts/partdetails/?id=47553
[image: Case Assembly Transaxle Assembly No. 120-7610]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it needed to look like your example, the inside of the gearbox would have mounting points for the inside bearings.  Casting would be typical, with the bearing surfaces machined smooth.  The X's on the shaft in your diagram infer such a mount.